# Getting "E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null" when run my code, using older api will that matter?

Tags: android

I'm going through a YouTube Tutorial on how to make an app with Android Studio and trying create an account using google firebase, and get the following error:

```
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

I've look around the internet and on Youtube but since its and older SDK (Android 5.0 Lollipop with API 21) and im using Android Studio 2019 of August I didnt know if that was an issue, also i dont know what code to post because i dont know where the error is.

Comment: can you include a link to the youtube tutorial you are watching ?

Comment: Here is the Playlist: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxefhmF0pcPnTQ2oyMffo6QbWtztXu1W_

Here is the video i am on:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHbV6kNkMC4&list=PLxefhmF0pcPnTQ2oyMffo6QbWtztXu1W_&index=10&t=549s

that is where it all stopped working